# JasperReports JDBC TDS: internal error 2

Tags: java, jdbc, jasper-reports, jtds

I am trying to fill a jrxml file using JasperCompileManager and I am receiving the following error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : MSWST
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:240)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1114)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:691)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1288)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:907)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:852)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:87)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillToFile(JasperFillManager.java:228)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillToFile(JasperFillManager.java:124)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(JasperFillManager.java:666)
at DbReportFill.generateReport(DbReportFill.java:57)
at DbReportFill.main(DbReportFill.java:160)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: TDS: internal error 2
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:505)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:1029)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:233)
... 12 more
```

The connection looks like this:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:jtds:sybase://127.0.0.1:2631/serverName", "DBA",
            "password");
```

I had heard that this may ocurre do to the driver, but i get the same error when I am using jconn3.